# How do I print variables?

Tags: java

So I just started programming Java and they send a task where we had to create a personal ID where people introduces their data and then it will show you your data.
The problem comes the moment I have to print the variables, will show you below how does my vode look

```
Character nom;
do {
    System.out.print("Introdueix el teu nom: ");
    nom = tec.llegirCaracter();
    if (nom == null)
        System.out.println("Introdueix un nom vàlid");
} while (nom == null); 
System.out.println("La vostra fitxa ha estat creada correctament, aquí les vostres dades: ");
System.out.println("Nom: " + nom);
```

It will print just the first letter of the variable the user declares, for instance, if "nom" is declared to be John, it will only print "Nom: J" How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Use a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), instead of a single char?

Comment: Use `String`? Btw ... what is `tec.llegirCaracter()`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think it roughly means `getCharacter`

Comment: if it is just `getCharacter` this should work without issues ... so @Legoruu can you give the definition of `tec.llegirCaracter()` method ?

Comment: For people asking, tec-llegirCaracter() it's from a library the teacher gave us so the computer checks whether or not the variable is a Character, string etc.... I have solved the problem changing it from a Character to a String, thanks to all guys

Answer (score -1):

1.Use a string instead of a character and fix your loop condition.

2.`while(nom==null)` should be changed to `while(nom!=null)`
or use:

```
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String nom= sc.nextLine();  
    System.out.println("Nom:"+ nom);
```

Comment: if you use while(nom!=null) it never enters the loop.

Comment: Not sure if that's right. `while(nom==null)` basically means, run the loop till nom becomes not null in other words, if nom is null, which is of no use.